# Codeshare flight by non-EU airline. Am I able to claim delay compensation?

Tags: eu, delays, compensation, aeromexico

I was on a codeshare flight from Mexico City to Barcelona with a layover in Paris. The flight from Mexico City to Paris was operated by Aeroméxico and the flight from Paris to Barcelona was operated by Air France.

My flight to Paris was delayed for 5 hours because we had to wait for a new plane due to the original one having technical difficulties. This caused me to miss my connection. Aeroméxico arranged a hotel for me, and I could continue my travel to Barcelona the next day, causing me to reach my final destination more than 24 hours later than originally planned.

Am I able to claim compensation, given that the delayed flight was operated by a non-EU airline?

Does the fact that the flight was codeshared with an EU airline make any difference?

Comment: According to http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm and http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1476179175834&uri=CELEX:32004R0261, the EU compensation requirements only apply for flights to the EU if the **operating** air carrier is licensed in the EU. Here the operating air carrier is AeroMexico, so the EU rules don't apply.  The code share doesn't seem to be relevant.  Whether there is compensation available under Mexican law, I don't know.

Comment: @NateEldredge all intra-EU flights are covered by delay compensation. And I'm 99% sure the Paris-Barcelona flight wasn't operated by AirMexico.

Comment: @JonathanReez: But the flight from Paris to Barcelona wasn't delayed.  OP just didn't reach Paris in time to get on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_261/2004), no.

The flight operated by AeroMexico originating at MEX is exempt for not meeting this provision:

"travelling to an EU member state on an airline based in an EU member state"

AeroMexico is based in Mexico.